# New LED tube lights will only switch on if another light on the circuit is turned on

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have replaced the 48" T8 fluorescent tube lights in four separate single-tube ceiling fixtures in one room with direct-wire LED tubes, removing the ballasts in each one.  An adjacent room also has a ceiling fixture on the same circuit with a couple of screw-in LED bulbs.  Both rooms are controlled by wall switches, and the first room uses a pair of three-way switches.

As long as the light in the second room is turned on, the lights in the first room will also turn on and off correctly with either of its switches.  However, **if the second room light is off, the lights in the first room will not turn on until the second room light is also turned on, and they will stay on when that light is turned off!**  With the second room lights off, toggling the first room lights off and back on will not turn them on again until the second room lights are on as well.

The lights worked correctly prior to swapping the bulbs and removing the ballasts in the first room fixtures, and I did not touch any wiring outside the fixtures.  I'm stumped, thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Was all  your work on this confined to the interior or the fixtures themselves, or did you also take apart supply wiring at junction boxes or at switches?  How about "4-wire" connections to fixtures where 2 blacks and 2 whites from the ceiling were pigtailed to the ballasts, did you rearrange any of that?

Comment: Can you post a link to the specific bulbs you bought and their installation instructions?

Comment: To me it sounds like there may have been a switch loop in there and the possible following the standard color codes have things crossed up. Photos of boxes will help.

Comment: Are any of the switches dimmer switches or any other kind of electronic switch? Or are all the switches simple mechanical switches?

Comment: Most definitely a wiring screwup somewhere.  Fix it before someone gets zapped by voltage on a line that should be neutral.  (not saying that **you** messed things up, necessarily.  There may have been a previous problem that popped up when the ballasts were removed, etc.)

Comment: Yes, can you get us photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?